# dplyr: custum function in mutate. Uses full matrix instead of chunks?

Tags: r, dplyr, magrittr

Consider this example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

set.seed(123)
grp_s <- round(runif(4, 1, 10))
group <- rep(1:length(grp_s), grp_s)
dataF <- data.frame(grouping = group, var_a = runif(length(group)), var_b = runif(length(group)), var_c = runif(length(group)))

compute_it <- function(var_a, var_b){
    sum(var_a[var_b > .5], na.rm = TRUE)
}

dataF %<>%
        group_by(grouping) %>%
        mutate(fix_it = compute_it(var_a, var_b))
```

So far so good. Now instead of `compute_it` which takes as argument 
 column names, I would like to use a function which takes as argument 
 a chunk of the data (one chunk for each value of `grouping`).

something list using this function:

```
compute_it_2 <- function(Data){
    sum(Data$var_a[Data$var_b > .5], na.rm = TRUE)
}
```

where `compute_it` is used above. How to do that?

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for `do(s = fix_it(.))`. Or use `dataF %>% group_by(grouping) %>% nest() %>% mutate(s = map(data, fix_it2))`

Comment: @Axeman: none of these solution returns the original data frame with a new column fix_it_2 (they return complex data structure that one has to parse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also using `tidyr` and `purrr` we can either use `do` or `nest` first:

```
library(tidyverse)

dataF %>%
  group_by(grouping) %>%
  do(fix_it = compute_it_2(.)) %>% 
  unnest()
```

Giving:

> ```
> # A tibble: 4 × 2
>   grouping    fix_it
>      <int>     <dbl>
> 1        1 2.4065483
> 2        2 0.9568333
> 3        3 0.0000000
> 4        4 1.8274955
> ```

Or the nesting approach:

```
dataF %>% 
  group_by(grouping) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(fix_it = map_dbl(data, compute_it_2))
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 4 × 3
>   grouping             data    fix_it
>      <int>           <list>     <dbl>
> 1        1 <tibble [4 × 3]> 2.4065483
> 2        2 <tibble [8 × 3]> 0.9568333
> 3        3 <tibble [5 × 3]> 0.0000000
> 4        4 <tibble [9 × 3]> 1.8274955
> ```

If you `unnest()` the second option you get the original frame back:

> ```
> # A tibble: 26 × 5
>    grouping    fix_it     var_a      var_b      var_c
>       <int>     <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
> 1         1 2.4065483 0.9404673 0.96302423 0.12753165
> 2         1 2.4065483 0.0455565 0.90229905 0.75330786
> 3         1 2.4065483 0.5281055 0.69070528 0.89504536
> 4         1 2.4065483 0.8924190 0.79546742 0.37446278
> 5         2 0.9568333 0.5514350 0.02461368 0.66511519
> 6         2 0.9568333 0.4566147 0.47779597 0.09484066
> 7         2 0.9568333 0.9568333 0.75845954 0.38396964
> 8         2 0.9568333 0.4533342 0.21640794 0.27438364
> 9         2 0.9568333 0.6775706 0.31818101 0.81464004
> 10        2 0.9568333 0.5726334 0.23162579 0.44851634
> # ... with 16 more rows
> ```

Comment: Thanks! The last solution is the one